# error Traceback (most recent call last): after reading .txt file in Python

Tags: python, character-encoding

this is my first time trying to program in Python

```
with open('/Users/solidaneziri/Downloads/Data_Exercise_1.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line.split()[0])
```

this is the code that I wrote when reading the file and it complied and ran the first time, after the first time I keep getting this error and I don't know to fix it

```
/usr/bin/python3 /Users/solidaneziri/IdeaProjects/Abgabe1/src/BonusAufgabe/aufgabe1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/solidaneziri/IdeaProjects/Abgabe1/src/BonusAufgabe/aufgabe1.py", line 2, in <module>
    for line in infile:
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9f in position 190: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Has the content of the file changed since the first time that it was read?  If so, how was this change made?

Comment: Did you maybe save it with a different encoding than utf-8?

Comment: it didn't change, there are letters with accents and I think that's causing the problem  but idk how to import encoding and IntelliJ won't recognise it @snakecharmerb

Comment: @artie I downloaded it from the internet

Comment: Use correct `encoding` parameter in [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the letters with accents to normal ones and it worked. This is not the optimal Solution but it worked